# How to only import certain commands?

Tags: packages, soul

The `soul` package defines a ton of short macros, some of which I use regularly for my own writing.  I only need `\hl` and `\sethlcolor`.  Is there a way to load the package and only get those two commands?

Comment: It would be really cool if packages could export macros like e.g. Perl modules do it. Using options to only define certain macros is possible, but you can't load one package twice with different options. This would be a nice feature for LaTeX3: packages declare sets of non-clashing options and can be loaded multiple times using different combinations of these.

Comment: @Martin: One obvious part to this is the idea that document commands should be defined independently of internal material. How packages will be handled for LaTeX3 is still a long way off being discussed!

Answer (score 6):

Some packages allow to select the amount of defined macros using options, but I don't think the `soul` package provides such.

---

For very simple packages could be loaded in a group and only the wanted commands could be defined globally. However, this is getting complicated as soon this commands are using internal macros which of course also must be kept defined. The `soul` package is complex enough to make this a tedious task.

```
\begingroup
  \usepackage{<package>}
  \global\let\wantedmacro\wantedmacro
  \global\expandafter\let\csname special name\expandafter\endcsname\csname special name\endcsname
  % ...
\endgroup
```

Also some internal LaTeX macro which are defined for every loaded package must be handled, etc.

---

A better way would be to either only (re-)define the macros after loading the package, as Alan Munn already stated, or save and restore the macros in question around the `\usepackage`. This is necessary if the macros would be defined by another package which must be loaded beforehand for some reason.

```
\let\origsomemacro\somemacro % save the macro 
\let\somemacro\relax         % reset it, so it can be defined using `\newcommand` can be used without error
\usepackage{somepackage}     % load package
\let\altsomemacro\somemacro  % save that macro definition under a different name if required
\let\somemacro\origsomemacro % restore original definition
```

However, this might cause problems if the package relies on its own definition of these macros.

Comment: *if the package relies on its own definition of these macros* - which, judging from the package files I have read, I think is against accepted good practice in Latex, but is clearly not rare.

Comment: @Charles: I agree. Good packages have an internal definition which is used internally and the official user macro is `\let` to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the `soul` package and then use `\renewcommand` to define your own macros.